# Телеграмм бот с рандомными цифрами

Tags: бот, telegram

сам не шарю за программирование , пришел к вам знающим людям с вопросом. Нужен бот в ТГ , при команде который будет выдавать пять *рандомных* чисел от 1 до уанхандред. Прим.(25|17|99|45|11) можно с повторениями как в группе цифры так и в целом. Желательно не на тяжёлом движке , **спасибо**!

Comment: Вы ошиблись. Это не фриланс.

Comment: Просто ранее видел как готовый код скидывали на похожие темы.

Comment: Это нарушители закона))

Comment: Сорри если кого то оскорбил тем что попросил кодик на" 10 строк" )

Comment: Это за денюжку на другие ресурсы. Не сюда ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯   Тут ресурс о другом

Answer (score -1):

Создаем бота и получаем его токен [тут](https://telegram.me/botfather).

Используем [это](https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram-bot/), попутно читаем его [документацию](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a4/), что бы понять и разобраться как это работает.

Answer (score -1):

Используй модуль
import random

Вывод случайного числа при помощи использования random.random()
0.9461613475266107

```
import random
 
city_list = ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Philadelphia']
print("Выбор случайного города из списка - ", random.choice(city_list))
```

Answer (score -1):

Если коротко то примерно так:

```
import random

# задаем максимальное и минимальные значение множества из которого хотим получать случайное число
maxrandval = 101
minrandval = 1
# создаем списк в котором будем генерировавать и его же выводить
randvals = [0] * 5
# немного магии рандома для каждого числа в нашем списке
for i in range(5):
    randvals[i] = random.randint(minrandval, maxrandval)
print(*randvals)
```